# Continue sliding image after lifting mouse

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a small effect after sliding and lifting the mouse from an image. Currently when someone slides the image, it follows the mouse but after releasing it, it just stays exactly there, while I want it to continue moving towards the direction it was being slide into for a bit more decelerating and eventually stopping.

[Here](https://davetayls.github.io/jquery.kinetic/)  is an example of roughly what I want. Notice after stopping dragging the image it continues to move.

I am sorry if I am not explaining that well, please feel free to ask me anything you didnt understand.

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve]

Comment: You have a pretty good example at the above link. Why not try to right click and inspect it? It's not absolutely the most accessible but it looks like it's all there.